# Importing iOS ShareKit into Project Issue

Tags: ios, sharekit

I imported the ShareKit iOS Project 2.0 into my project. The ShareKit iOS Project and My project are residing into different folders.

In my project I have for example #import "Facebook.h"   which is residing at the ShareKit iOS project's ShareKit/Sharers/Facebook  folder.

Right Now, My project gave an error of unable to locate "Facebook.h"

Two Questions
1)Should I hardcode the path of ShareKit folder path into my Project Header Search PAth Section?

2) Does it make sense if I make a copy of files inside the ShareKit folder and imported directly into my project?

Comment: You need to import Sharekit framework to your project and other files from that sample.Check documentation properly.

Comment: I imported the ShareKit project as static library. right now my project couldn't locate the SHKTwitter.h, SHK.h, SHKFacebook.h...the headers files.

Comment: have you follow instruction properly of sharekit?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Sharekit]

Add your sharekit folder like this,and you will able to import required files to your project.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you should, definitely.
2. No, you do not have to. But your life would be much easier, if you followed [install wiki](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit) literally and downloaded shareKit as git submodule and added as subproject.

Wonder what is the reason you did not follow the wiki?